# RoR: How to show a due day instead of due date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, dayofweek

My application contains mobile views with Gmail style divs. Each div has a subject, name and due date.

The Due date column is a normal datetime value.

What I am looking to do is to have the first entries in the view show up as days for the last 6 days and then the rest show as datetime.

For example:

Mon
Tues
Wed
Wed
Thurs
Fri
2016/11/04
2016/11/03
.....

etc.

How can this be best achieved? I don't think I need to post code for this question but I will if required.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Not working...

In view...

```
<font size="1"><strong>Due:</strong> <%= homework.formatted_date(due) %></font>&emsp;&ensp;
```

In ApplicationController...(not sure if I have syntax correct...)

```
helper_method :formatted_date

def formatted_date(due)
  if (Date.today - due).abs < 6
    due.strftime('%A')
  else
    due.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
  end
end
```

The view loads but the dates show same as before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a helper for your view... put it in ApplicationController

```
helper_method :formatted_date

def formatted_date(item_date)
  if (Date.today - item_date).abs < 6
    item_date.strftime('%A')
  else
    item_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
  end
end
```

Then in your view, instead of showing the `object_date` field show `formatted_date(object_date)`

Comment: Thanks, I put in your suggestion exactly in the Application Helper but get undefined method `helper_method' for ApplicationHelper:Module.  In my view: <td height="1"><%= homework.formatted_date(due) %></td>

Comment: @Co2 `helper_method` is used in *controllers* to make methods available as view helpers, you don't need that if your method is defined in `ApplicationHelper`.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn   Thanks both for your help. It's still not working, I have updated the OP. Perhaps I have not followed properly?

Comment: No no no it's `<%= formatted_date(homework.due)  %>` the method you created is not a homework object method.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thank you so much! It works :D Silly me!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Sorry to bother you again. The laying out of the full name of a day distorts my view a little, I was just wondering is there a way to say "Wed" for example instead of full "Wednesday"? Thanks!

Comment: Use %a instead of %A the full list is here http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks, I tried this but for some reason it does not work and the day renders the same. I don't know why.

Comment: Be sure to stop and start your server.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I did, still the same. This is what I have: if (Date.today - due).abs < 6
    due.strftime('%a')
  else...